# what's the complexity of Exists C#?

Tags: c#

What's the complexity of the method Exists in a list, I have this:

```
List<ComplexData> list = new List<ComplexData>()
list.Exists( r => r.Name == someValue );
```

My class has the values:

```
public class ComplexData
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Descripcion { get; set; }
}
```

I've looking for the complexity and I've tried executing some loops but the time doesn't change so much. I don't know if the list create an "index" like a database or if make some order by the comparator and then do a binarySearch.

Comment: It's `O(n)` more details [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfed8bca(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: As others mentioned, it's O(n). If you want a faster lookup, consider using a `Dictionary<string, ComplexData>` that's keyed against your `Name` property. EDIT: But this would assume that `Name` is unique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Source code is open, you can find it [here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs,c4784f7f51679ee9)

The method basically goes through every element in collection till it finds a match.

```
public bool Exists(Predicate<T> match)
{
    return FindIndex(match) != -1;
}

public int FindIndex(Predicate<T> match)
{
    Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<int>() >= -1);
    Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<int>() < Count);
    return FindIndex(0, _size, match);
}

public int FindIndex(int startIndex, int count, Predicate<T> match)
{
    if ((uint) startIndex > (uint) _size)
    {
        ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException(ExceptionArgument.startIndex,
            ExceptionResource.ArgumentOutOfRange_Index);
    }

    if (count < 0 || startIndex > _size - count)
    {
        ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException(ExceptionArgument.count,
            ExceptionResource.ArgumentOutOfRange_Count);
    }

    if (match == null)
    {
        ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentNullException(ExceptionArgument.match);
    }
    Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<int>() >= -1);
    Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<int>() < startIndex + count);
    Contract.EndContractBlock();

    int endIndex = startIndex + count;
    for (int i = startIndex; i < endIndex; i++)
    {
        if (match(_items[i])) return i;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the C# Documentation on Microsoft's website:

**Remarks**

> The Predicate is a delegate to a method that returns true if the object passed to it matches the conditions defined in the delegate. The elements of the current List are individually passed to the Predicate delegate, and processing is stopped when a match is found.
>
> This method performs a linear search; therefore, this method is an O(n) operation, where n is Count.

See it here: [List.Exists](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfed8bca(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The complexity is O(n).

`Exists` internally uses `FindIndex`.
There's no index creation, basically `Exists` loops all items in a collection until it finds one that matches your predicate.

Try 10 million elements and you'll see how slow it gets when compared with a `Hashset` with the same number of elements.

`Hashset` has O(1) complexity